# Displaying a static wordpress home page. After this blog posts not showing up correctly

Tags: wordpress

Through settings I set to show one static page (lets say I called it "static") as index page. And a blog page as a second page whch you can reach via menu. The static page is displayed just fine, but when I want to open any page with blog template (dynamic content) I get just the name "static", username and the date, and its displayed only once. Nothing more. I dont have an idea of where I could look for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which wordpress version you are using? 
Hope you done it like this(Double check it).
Settings > Reading > Front Page Display.
Then you select the "A static page" radio button. And sets both "Fron Page" and "Post Page".

Also for further investigation, can you provide the site link?